# Generate CommonJS compatible bundle for Node.js from ES6 using Webpack/Babel

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, node-modules

**Is it possible to tell Webpack to generate CommonJS instead of ES6 style exports for the bundle (other than switching all my files to use `require`)?**

I'm using Webpack v5 and Babel v7, targeting NodeJS v12.

I've configured Webpack to use `@babel/preset-env`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['env', {
                modules: false,
                useBuiltIns: 'usage'
              },
                "@babel/env",
                {
                  "targets": {
                    "node": "12"
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
```

Transpilation to ES6 looks fine, except when I load my module (targeting AWS Lambda/NodeJS v12) it is not able to load my module due to the exports are of seemingly wrong type (see code below).

---

More details:

The only way to get the code to run is to ensure all source code only uses `require`. If I switch to `import` then the export directives in the transpiled code changes. The export directive is `__webpack_exports__` instead of `exports` when I user `import` instead of `require`:

#### CommonJS (`require`):

```
module.exports =
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ 946:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports, __webpack_require__) => {
```

#### ES6 (`import`):

```
module.exports =
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ 993:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {
```

Note: I've tried to specify `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, but this causes the following error:

```
[webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /src/web-app/webpack.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

There is a similar question, but it seems outdated (using `babel-loader/env`): [Is it possible to compile to commonjs from es6 with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309877/is-it-possible-to-compile-to-commonjs-from-es6-with-webpack)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile to commonjs from es6 with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309877/is-it-possible-to-compile-to-commonjs-from-es6-with-webpack)

Comment: @arseneyr It is similar, but I already use preset-env to target node v12. There seems to be no config setting to specify CommonJS exports (I assumed that would happen when targeting node v12 specifically)

Comment: Seems maybe `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` is the answer...